# Liquibase diff - Driver issue

Tags: postgresql, command-line, driver, diff, liquibase

i tried to make a

> liquibase xml with **liquibase diff**

command.

I want to do this based on this documentation: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html

If I try to exec the example command with my custom properties,
with

**--driver:org.postgresql.Driver**,
I got this problem:

> "Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the classpath where the driver jar file is located using the *classpath* key ([liquibase documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html)).

Your properties file should look like:

```
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
classpath: postgresql-driver.jar
url: jdbc:postgres@localhost:5432
username: scott 
password: tiger
```

Comment: Any idea, how to mention multiple classpaths. Say, we are doing a diff between multiple drivers